# PHP comments appearing on the webpage

Tags: php, html

I commented out PHP comments on my script. but they still appear on my webpage in HTML. Do you have any idea how do I fix this?

kind regards,

```
/*if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
//require_once is similar to 'include' but ensures the code is not copied multiple times
require_once('LoginFunctions.php');*/
```

this text appear on my webpage:
[image: the output]

my whole script:
Here is my whole script so you can identify where the mistake is.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
include 'Header.php';
?>

<style>
    body
    {
        background-color:#FFFFC2;
        alignment-adjust: central; 
        float: none;
        background-image: url("images_1/sea-sanctuaries-siteimage01.jpg");
        alignment-baseline: central;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height:100%;
    }
    #div_1 {
        width: 40%;
        hight: 80%;
        background-color: bisque;
        border: 5px;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }

    #div_2 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <br>


        <?php
        /*
          if($_DEBUG)
          {
          ini_set('display_errors', 1);
          ini_set('log_errors', 1);
          ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
          error_reporting(E_ALL);
          }


          $page_title = 'Login';/* */

//in this page we do things slightly differently - the code for validation and displaying messages is done
//before we display the form 
        echo '<div id = "div_1><h1>Login</h1>';

//display the form
        echo '<div id="div_2"><div id="div_2">
   <form action="index.php" method="post">
       <label>UserName<br>
       <span class="small">enter your username</span>
       </label>
       <input type="text" name="UserName" value=""/>

       <label><br>Password<br>
       <span class="small">enter your password</span>
       </label>
       <input type="password" name="Password" />

       <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />Log in</button>
       <input type ="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE">
     </form>
     </div>
</div>';

        /* if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
          //require_once is similar to 'include' but ensures the code is not copied multiple times
          require_once('LoginFunctions.php');

          //list() is a way of assigning multiple values at the same time
          //checkLogin() function returns an array so list here assigns the values in the array to $check and $data
          list($check, $data) = checkLogin($_POST['UserName'], $_POST['Password']);


          if ($check) {
          setcookie('FName', $data['FName'], time()+ 900 ) ;  //cookie expires after 15 mins
          setcookie('LName', $data['LName'], time() + 900 ) ;
          //
          //use session variables instead of cookies
          //these variables should now be available to all pages in the application as long as the users session exists
          $_SESSION['FName'] = $data['FName'];
          $_SESSION['LName'] = $data['LName'];
          $_SESSION['UserName'] = $data['UserName'];
          //to enable $_SESSION array to be populated we always need to call start_session() - this is done in header.php

          //print_r is will print out the contents of an array
          //print_r($_SESSION);
          //
          //Redirect to another page
          $url = absolute_url('Index.php');  //function defined in Loginfunctions.php to give absolute path for required page
          $logged = true;
          //this version of the header function is used to redirect to another page
          header("Location: $url");//since we have entered correct login details we are now being directed to the home page

          exit();
          } else {
          $errors = $data;
          }
          }

          //create a sopace between the button and the error messages
          echo'<div class="spacer"></div>';

          if (!empty($errors)) {
          echo '<br/> <p class="error">The following errors occurred: <br />';

          //foreach is a simplified version of the 'for' loop
          foreach ($errors as $err) {
          echo "$err <br />";
          }

          echo '</p>';
          }

          //this is the end of the <div> that contains the form
          echo '</div>';

          /* */
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

<?php
include 'Footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: i'll post the code now, its long so i'll post part of it

Comment: try this it works for me :/*if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
require_once is similar to 'include' but ensures the code is not copied multiple times
require_once('LoginFunctions.php');*/

Comment: also - note that require_once() is not simply a method for preventing multiple actions. There is also include_once() which achieves the same effect. The difference between them lies in the action if an error occurs. You may need to research which is required for your code.

Comment: looks like your WAMP is broken - your code does not display comments here

Answer (score 1):

comment them inside PHP code sections

```
<?php /*  code here will not display in html */ ?>

<!-- code here will be visible (in view source) -->
```

If your php interpreter is not running there's no way to hide php code.

Comment: that's what I did, i'll upload my whole script

Comment: it could be that you've got a problem before the comment that makes PHP think that what you want to be a comment is a string

Comment: I'm using a software named "WAMP" which creates for me a local server. we did not go into details. But this is the only time it siaplayed such thing. At other times, it did not

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one `"` in the line

```
echo '<div id = "div_1><h1>Login</h1>';
```

which apparently causes it, somehow, to continue echoing what comes after.

Solution: add the missing `"` after the `div_1`